# Using a symbolic link under files

Tags: files, 9

In our Drupal installation, I need a file repository that survives deploys and gets some special treatments, so I thought I could use a symbolic link to a NAS mount point below `web/sites/default/files`. Unfortunately, this does not work with `FileRepository`; for example, if I call `FileRepository::writeData()`, down below the call chain I reach `FileSystem::prepareDirectory()`, that uses `is_dir()` to check that the destination is indeed a directory, and it fails the check when the destination is an URI. For example,

```
var_dump(is_dir('/var/www/senato/cls.senato.it/current/web/sites/default/files/repo')) ;
var_dump(is_dir('public://repo')) ;
```

shows

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

I'd have expected that subdirectories of `repo` would at least be checked as directories, but that is not the case.

I suppose it is due to the `public://` wrapper, but I have no idea whether that is a correct behaviour or not.

Is there any way to have a symbolic link in the `files` directory?

EDIT: I was so convinced there should a way to do this that I didn't search for it thoroughly enough, now I found [this](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1008402), so I'll change my question: is this still the way to go? Any chance it will be incorporated into 9.x or 10.x, sooner or later?

Comment: I got around this problem by configuring a `private` directory with the path `web/sites/default/repo` and having this directory point to the NAS mount point; I lose public URLs, but I don't really need them. I may have left `repo` below `files`, but since I lose public URLs anyway I prefer to keep it outside, so there is a cleaner separation between the files managed by Drupal core and those managed by my module.